# ¿Es Posible Convertir Un Outpustream O Un InputStream En Un File Común?

Tags: java, android, google-drive

¿Es posible convertir un `Outputstream` o un `Inputstream` en un `File`? Lo necesito porque los métodos para abrir el contenido de un archivo en google drive son compatibles con `Inputstream` o `Outputstream` y no con los `Files`.

Explico: quiero ser capas de acceder a los datos de un `DriveFile` desde un `File` utilizando un conversión de `OutputStream` o `InputStream` a `File` con el fin de que ese archivo pueda ser ejecutado por el sistema como un ordinario.

Comment: Creo que puede confundir un poco si lo requieres en java o para android ha que ser mas específico Saludos!!

Comment: @SoftMolina es indistinto, para Java eso no es tan relevante.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Gracias por el dato lo comente por que como Abraham.P comento en la publicación de abajo que para android no le servia.

Comment: @SoftMolina lo que no le servía era la inclusión de la librería. Mi respuesta está basada en Java puro, y adicionalmente el uso de librerías.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando Java puro, sin librerías:

```
//copiaremos el contenido del stream en bloques de 4 KBytes
static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

public void creaArchivo(String ruta, InputStream is)
    throws IOException {
    //BufferedOutputStream es para escribir el contenido del stream
    //por partes para no llenar la memoria y porque es más rápido
    //FileOutputStream es para indicar que vamos a escribir el
    //contenido en un archivo
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta)));
    byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesLeidos = 0;
    //mientras que podamos leer bytes del stream de entrada
    //en bloques de tamaño CHUNK_SIZE
    while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {
        //escribir los bytes leidos en el arreglo
        //desde la posición 0 hasta la posición marcada por
        //el valor de la variable bytesLeidos
        os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
    }
    os.close();
}
```

Si no quieres escribir este código, puedes agregar la librería [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) y usar el método `IOUtils#copy(InputStream, OutputStream)`.

Luego de escribir el archivo en el disco local, como ya tienes la ruta, puedes hacer lo que sigue:

```
File file = new File(ruta);
```

Considera que ni `InputStream` ni `OutputStream` conocen información del archivo con el que trabajan, solo saben que hay un flujo de bytes al cual deben leer (`InputStream`) o escribir (`OutputStream`).

Comment: Su código me ha ayudado gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar la matriz de bytes.

```
//OutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(new File(archivoSalidaFile));

//byte[] -> InputStream
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( outputStream.toByteArray() )
```

Esta es una forma sencilla de convertir de OutputStream a InputStream en Java.

Comment: No he votado en contra, pero el problema de esta implementación es que cargas todo el archivo en memoria y luego lo vuelcas. Si estás transfiriendo archivos muy pesados explotarás la RAM o la aplicación dejará de funcionar por OOME

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si tienes mucha razón puede funcionar pero no con archivos muy pesados, me gusto tu respuesta usando java puro Saludos!!

Answer (score -2):

Para crear un `File` a partir de un `InputStream` se puede con la librería de [apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyInputStreamToFile(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.File)):

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(el_inputStream, el_File);
```

Hay que entender que  `InputStream` es de donde se lee.

Mientras que `OutputStream` es a donde se escribe, por lo que no veo éste para qué te serviría en éste caso.

### Edit

Se supone que [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Compatibility) es compatible con android, por lo que probablemente [ésto](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained) te ayude.

Comment: En android no esta incluida en el sdk la clase FileUtils de java ni la clase Files. Gracias

Comment: Ah!  no me percaté de la etiqueta android, lo siento!

Comment: No hay porque sentirlo al menos a mi no me funciona, pero quien sabe si a otro le sirve.

Comment: Así no esté en Android, no necesitas de ninguna librería externa para convertir un `InputStream` a un archivo.

Comment: No significa que no se pueda Luiggi, es una opción. Hay muchas formas de realizar las cosas...

Comment: Y lo mejor es sin librerías, es más limpio y entiendes mejor las cosas. En caso que se pueda, pues agrega las librerías.